# Can I add query conditions on setting up .on listener?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to setup .on listener for check if there is a new object added to `videos` ref. What I did is like the following. When a new video is added to `videos` ref, will this listener capture this event? Thanks!

```
  admin
    .database()
    .ref("videos")
    .orderByChild("createdAt")
    .limitToLast(1)
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it has the highest value of createdAt compared to all of the other children under videos.  But it's entirely possible that the listener might miss a child in the event of a race condition or dropping offline during several updates.

Keep in mind that Realtime Database doesn't send "events" to clients.  It synchronizes data.  You can't be guaranteed that each new video shows up as a distinct "event" in your listener.  If you want to handle database writes in a more properly even-driven way, you should set up something on the backend with [Cloud Functions database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to respond to changes, then reflect that to the clients as needed.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I do have cloud function to add the new video object to the realtime database. I need to query the db on the client's side to make sure the db is truly added. So I think the .on listener may help. If it's not guaranteed, can I use the .once("value") query in a loop to check if there is  some new video in the db?

Comment: If the client knows what it's looking for, it should just use that to identify the thing to wait on, as opposed to a timestamp.  It's very common to use unique IDs for this.  When the client and server agree on an ID, that becomes an exchange point for the server to notify the client that something interesting changed.

Comment: Totally make sense Doug! Thanks again!